# Как правильно использовать абстрактные методы?

Tags: java

Всем привет. Нужно мнение опытных разработчиков Java.
У меня есть абстрактный класс Client

```
public abstract class Client {
    protected double amount;

    double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void put(double amountToPut) {
        if (amountToPut > 0) {
            amount += amountToPut;
            System.out.println(amount);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Неправильная сумма");
        }
    }

    protected void take(double amountToTake) {
        if (amountToTake < amount) {
            amount -= amountToTake;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Неправильная сумма");
        }
    }

    public abstract void getInfo();

}
```

У него есть наследники:

1. PhisicalPerson - переопределяет getInfo();
2. IndividualBusinessman - переопределяет getInfo() и put();
3. LegalPerson - переопределяет getInfo() и take();

Я сделал абстрактным только один метод getInfo(), чтобы избежать дублирование кода в наследниках, но преподаватель со мной не согласен.
А теперь вопрос - как правильно распределять назначение абстрактных методов в таком случае? Может есть какая-то статья по этому поводу?

Comment: По какому поводу? По поводу что ожидает ваш конкретный преподаватель? Вы скинули один класс без особых пояснений чего либо. Тут даже задачу вашу не понять, не то, чтобы какие то советы давать.

Comment: Если вас  интересует только назначение абстрактных методов, первая ссылка в гугле ведет на википедию, где есть раздел про назначение.

Comment: Вот комментарий преподавателя:
Смысл абстракций (и вообще принципов ООП) не в том, чтобы избежать дублирования кода, а чтобы выстроить логичную систему иерархий (один из смыслов).

Comment: И я не понимаю, почему мой вариант с одним только абстрактным методом, который обязаны переопределять все наследники, считается неправильным.
getInfo() несет в себе информацию об условиях пополнения и снятия средств в каждой реализации Клиента. В наследниках простые методы, поэтому не выкладывал остальные классы. Вики я читал. Абстрактный метод ничего не делает, но определяет параметры и возвращаемое значение. 
Вот и у меня один ничего не делает и требует реализации от всех.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас в вашем примере плохо все, потому нет смысла говорить о какой то одной мелочи. Давайте разберем ваш пример.

### Начем с названий.

Почему класс называется `Client`? В чем назначение этого класса? Чтобы быть базовым классом для других классов-клиентов? Тогда почему не `BaseClient`?

Клиентом чего этот класс должен быть? Банка? Как по названию класса понять для чего он нужен? Если вы пишете базовый класс для клиентов банка, так и называйте его `BaseBankClient` или как то похоже, чтобы было ясно, для чего этот класс вообще нужен.

Следующее, `protected double amount;` - это количество чего? Яблок и груш? Или денег? Если это количество денег (`moneyAmount`?), то это суммарное их количество на счете? (и почему вообще сумма денег на счете хранится в клиенте, а не в банке?) Или у вас тут нет счетов? Ок, допустим, у вас нет счета и это количество денег, в какой они валюте? Ок, допустим валюта не важна, тогда почему это число с поаващей точкой? У вас может быть 0.0000001 рубль на счету? Название и тип этого поля нестолько непонятные, что читать этот код скорее вредно, чем полезно.

Дальше, смотрим на методы `public void put(double amountToPut)` и `protected void take(double amountToTake)`. Имя параметра говорит о передаваемых данных, имя функции говорит о выполняемом действии. То есть нет необходимости в имени параметра писать, что вы делать собрались, потому если вам надо сделать `put` некоторого `amount`, так и пишите `public void put(double amount)`. Но даже это не лучший вариант. А что, если у вас будет 2 поля типа `double` в классе?  Как вы будете между ними разгранничивать операции? `public void put(double amount1)` и `public void put(double amount2)` работать не будет для разных полей. Потому, возвращаемся к `Имя параметра говорит о передаваемых данных, имя функции говорит о выполняемом действии.` - ваши операции будут выглядеть как `public void putAmount(double value)` и `public void takeAmount(double value)`.

Смотрим следующую функцию. `public abstract void getInfo();` - вот я читаю первый раз ваш код. Что я из этой строчки должен понять? Вы информацию о чем возврашаете? О фазе луны? И почему функция, которая называется "получитьИнформацию" не возвращает ничего? Вы спрашиваете как её надо было написать, но я лично не понимаю зачем она вообще тратит место в вашем коде.

Остальные названия вашиз классов - `PhisicalPerson`, `IndividualBusinessman`, `LegalPerson` - это все клиенты? Тогда почему не `PhysicalPersonBankClient`?

### Доступ

В вашем коде просто мешанина уровней доступа. У вас поле `amount` сделано защищенным, а `getAmount()` - package private. Это зачем?

У вас операция `put` - публичная, а `take` - защищенная, в чем тут смысл?

### Логика

Смотрим на ваш метод `put`.

```
public void put(double amountToPut) {
    if (amountToPut > 0) {
        amount += amountToPut;
        System.out.println(amount);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Неправильная сумма");
    }
}
```

Вопросы:

1. Почему метод, который предназначем для увеличения суммы на счету, вдруг начинает что то выводить в консоль? Вы читали про SRP (это буква S из SOLID)? Почему вообше клиент занимается выводом в консоль?
2. Вы проверяете взходной параметр `amountToPut > 0`, ок, это хорошо. Но почему при неверном входном параметре вы опять пишете в консоль? Вот я запущу ваш класс, вызову метод, а консоли у меня нет - как мне понять, сделал ли метод свою работу? Вы слышали про исключения?

### DRY

Вы мотивируете свои решения в ООП уменьшением кода. Но вот скажите, зачем вам тогда отдельные функции для изменения баланса? Почему вы меняете поле `amount` в разных местах своего класса? Не проще ли было бы написать единственную функцию по изменению amount и там уже все, что надо проверять?

```
public void changeAmount(double value)
{
    double newAmount = amount + value; 
    if (newAmount > 0) amount = newAmount;
    else throw new InvalidArgumentException("amount cannot be less than zero");
}
```

Ок, если вы хотие поддерживать и валидировать операции `put` и `take`, вам не кажется, что они обе НЕ должны работать напрямую с полем `amount`?

```
public void put(double amountToPut) {
    if (amountToPut > 0) {            
        changeAmount(-amountToPut);
        System.out.println(getAmount());
    } else {
        System.out.println("Неправильная сумма");
    }
}

protected void take(double amountToTake) {
    if (amountToTake < getAmount()) {
        changeAmount(-amountToTake);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Неправильная сумма");
    }
}
```

Использование функций типа `changeAmount` очень важно, так как имея единую точку доступа к изменению значения поля `amount` вы держите ее под контролем. Код выше гарантирует, что amount не станет меньше 0 ни при каких обстоятельствах. Ваш же код, особенно вот это `protected double amount;` - позволяет менять поле `amount` вообще кому попало и вы не можете гарантировать ничего.

Я надеюсь теперь стало понятно, почему я вам в комментариях написал, что здесь не ясна ни ваша задача, ни ваш вопрос. У кода, что вы написали, есть горазо большие проблемы, чем какая то абстрактная функция.

Comment: Во-первых, спасибо за такой развернутый ответ по коду! Мне, как учащемуся, очень познавательно, я сохраню в заметках.

Comment: Во-вторых, т.к. это обучение, то тут часть кода, названия методов и переменных приходят в качестве условий задания.
public abstract class Client {

    public double getAmount() {
        //TODO: реализуйте метод и удалите todo
        return 0;
    }

    public void put(double amountToPut) {
        //TODO: реализуйте метод и удалите todo
    }

    public void take(double amountToTake) {
        //TODO: реализуйте метод и удалите todo
    }

}

Comment: Мы еще не проходили исключения, поэтому все неправильное выводим в консоль.
Про модификаторы доступа - package-private сделано Идеей, я уже почитал про модификаторы, и в ближайшем будущем вряд ли у меня будет что-то кроме public и private.

Comment: Условия задания
Цель задания
Освоить работу с наследованием, используя абстрактный класс.
Что нужно сделать
В проекте найдите абстрактный класс Client и его наследников IndividualBusinessman, LegalPerson и PhysicalPerson.
Реализуйте методы классов, при необходимости переопределите методы в наследниках так, чтобы выполнялись условия пополнения и снятия:

Comment: Основная задача для меня понять как определить какие методы стоит делать абстрактными, а какие нет.

Comment: @БорисСамойлов ну тогда добавьте в вопрос ваши мысли и что говорит преподаватель. Вот вы пишете про уменьшение кода, но ООП не для этого. Абстрактный метод явно говорит, что этот метод не имеет поведения по умолчанию, но при этом каждый наследник класса должен знать его реализацию. Самому же базовому классу не иснересно, как именно его наследники будут метод реализовывать. То есть сокращение кода в данном случае не имеет тут значения. Тут имеет значение вопрос - а есть ли у метода реализация по умолчанию, которая имеет смысл для базового класса?

Comment: Исходя из вашего комментария, я делаю вывод. что в моем случае правильно будет реализовать в Клиенте только геттер на amount, что имеет смысл для базового класса, т.к. он только возвращает значение переменной и это также работает для всех наследников.
А все остальные методы будут абстрактными, потому что базовый класс не может продумать наперед логику реализации этих методов в наследниках, поведение в них может быть разным. Правильно?

Comment: @БорисСамойлов этого я не знаю, вы же так и не показали свое задание и свое решение полностью. А по этим частям, что вы скинули, сложно что то сказать.